# Нарисовать график функции

Tags: actionscript

Пожалуйста, помогите. Нужно нарисовать график функции `x=wt (w-omega)` в Flash Action script.

Comment: <a href="http://translit.ru/">translit.ru</a> пользуйтесь

Comment: @Sarvar, убедительно прошу вас пользоваться кириллицей.

Comment: Стараюсь, но я плохо пишу в кириллицей, потому что я из Узбекистана.

Answer (score 1):

```
var w:int = 2; // эмуляция функции 
var y:int = 0; // 't

var spr:Sprite = new Sprite(); // экранный объект на котором рисуем
spr.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x00ff00); // толщина и цвет
spr.graphics.moveTo(0,0); // начальные коорды

for ( y=0; y<101;y++ ) //итерируем 't
{
    spr.graphics.lineTo(y * w, y); // линия в новую точку
}

stage.addChild(spr); // показываем наш спрайт
```

Comment: Не получается :( Не отображается на экран.

Comment: разговор слепого с глухим

давай код, весь

Comment: ya napisal eti kodi na flash mx, grafik ne otobrajaetsya

Comment: я написал этот код на action script 3, график отображается, да

Comment: в Action script3 такое ошибка: 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition flash.display:DisplayObject.y in namespace public. var y:int = 0; // 't

Comment: переименовать надо - y